# Using machine learning to parse complicated strings containing chemical data?

Tags: python, parsing, machine-learning

I have very poor (dirty?) chemical information data, that has the following format:

```
ID  Chemicals
1701    3 Tanks - 1 - Benzoyl Chloride and 2 - Benzoflex
1840    Two 520 Class IIIB inside and Two 16,800 Condensate tanks
1840    Two 520 Class IIIB inside and Two 16,800 Condensate tanks
1938    2 tanks - 1,100 gallons diesel & 1,100 gallons gasoline
1888    4 tanks - 3 - 20,000 gallon and 1 - 10,000 gallon  Gas, Diesel and K-1
```

I need to parse this data to search for recognizable chemicals in each super-string. After parsing this data, I can search through commonly available chemistry databases for the subsets to return hits (of different quality) for each subset. The main problem is that I don't know how to begin parsing this data in an efficient and structured manner.  There are several ideas I am toying with:

1. Parse each superstring into all combinations of substrings, using whitespaces as a delimiter for the substrings, and then search for all combinations of the substrings.
2. Do the above, but only after removing key words I know not to be useful (tanks, class, inside, etc.)
3. Use a machine learning algorithm with supervised learning to parse the data - with the supervised learning being feedback from me on whether the parsed data was useful in supplying a useful match from the external chemistry database

Right now I am attempting method 2, after implementing method 1 with horrible results, but I am finding that building and maintaining the list of 'keys' to ignore is proving far too cumbersome.

If I wish to follow option three, what python machine learning libraries can provide this capability?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider:

- Start with a a comprehensive chemistry vocabulary.
- Perform an n-gram (maybe 3 or 4?) parsing of your super strings
- Retain only those ngrams containing at least one term found within the chemistry vocabulary
- Perform further analyses on those chemistry-related results from within each superstring

You will have narrowed your input data to focus only on the chemistry related elements: so then many analytical tools/algorithms may be subsequently applied.